# use jquery to get id of input field to pass back color change

Tags: jquery, css, input, this, attr

hoping somebody can point me in the right direction.
I know there are similar questions, but I havn't found one that deals directly with what I'm trying to achieve.
I'm trying to get the id of an input field so I can change font-color.

```
<div id="red">
    <input id="redA" type="text">
    <input id="redB" type="text">
    <input id="redC" type="text">
</div>
<div id="outerContainer">
    <div id="innerContainer">
        <div id="blue">
             <input id="blueA" type="text" onBlur="check()">
             <input id="blueB" type="text" onBlur="check()">
             <input id="blueC" type="text" onBlur="check()">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

<script>
    function check(){
        var v=$(this).val();
        if ( v=="red" ) { $(this).css({"color":"red"})
        if ( v=="green" ) { $(this).css({"color":"green"})
        if ( v=="blue" ) { $(this).css({"color":"blue"})
    }
</script>
```

I know this is a bit long winded, but hopefully it can be seen what im trying to do
Thanks

Comment: You mean like ``this.id`` or ``$(this).attr('id')``?

Comment: try this @nathan http://jsfiddle.net/L9c44rba/

Comment: btw. you seem to have a typo in you code: should be `var v=$(this).val();` instead of `var v=(this).val();`

Comment: i tried... var id=$(this).attr('id'); but does not seem to work either

Comment: ahh yes, i did see that but i wrote it quick on here to give an idea of what im trying to do, thanks

Comment: thanks @Sushil, works great, im going to try and apapt it to call it as a function instead of in the document head, thanks again

Comment: you're welcome @nathan :) please mark it as an answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
<div id="red">
    <input id="redA" type="text">
    <input id="redB" type="text">
    <input id="redC" type="text">
</div>
<div id="outerContainer">
    <div id="innerContainer">
        <div id="blue">
             <input id="blueA" type="text" onblur="check(this)">
             <input id="blueB" type="text" onblur="check(this)">
             <input id="blueC" type="text" onblur="check(this)">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function check(vObj){
    console.log($(vObj));
    var v=$(vObj).val();
    if ( v=="red" ) { $(vObj).css({"color":"red"}); }
    if ( v=="green" ) { $(vObj).css({"color":"green"}); }
    if ( v=="blue" )  { $(vObj).css({"color":"blue"}); }
}
```

here's the jsfiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/afPrc/109/

the reason your fiddle was not working was because you were not passing the object of your textbox to the function. when you do `$(this)` inside the function, it gets the object of `window` instead of the `textbox`.

Comment: hi, thanks, ive made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NathanUK/enLsnued/ but its not working, i want to keep it as a seperate function, thanks

Comment: @nathan you can have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/afPrc/109/ the reason your fiddle was not working was because you were not passing the object of your textbox to the function. when you do $(this) inside the function, it gets the object of window instead of the textbox.

Comment: hey, thanks @Sushhil, works a treat, but it does cause me a problem... in my example above i didnt parse a variable when calling the function, but that is what i want to do, i'm guessing the smoothest way is to  check(vObj, f) in this example, thanks again its been doing my head in. '

Comment: yeah sure, but its its the one on the fiddle that did the trick, so if you post that as an answer i'll mark it, thanks

Comment: @nathan I've updated my answer. please mark it as a solution and upvote it if it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/mzzq6ef9/

```
<div id="red">
        <input id="redA" type="text">
        <input id="redB" type="text">
        <input id="redC" type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="outerContainer">
        <div id="innerContainer">
            <div id="blue">
                 <input id="blueA" type="text">
                 <input id="blueB" type="text">
                 <input id="blueC" type="text">
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>

$("input").focus(function(){
    var v = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    if ( v =="red" ) { 
        $(this).css({"color":"red"});
    } else if ( v=="green" ) { 
        $(this).css({"color":"green"});
    } else { 
        $(this).css({"color":"blue"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply @DavidBucka, but.. its called on focus rather than blur and its not getting the value and id as seperate things as in my example

Answer (score 0):

okay, I find that I have been a bit dopey here by not using 'this' in any way that's correct.

In case anybody comes this and needs an easy answer, like I did.
My mistake was that I was trying to identify the element by specifically gaining and using the id. I did not need to do this as 'this' comes in handy here.

By putting 'this' in brackets of the function request, it tells the function it means this one!!

an easy example

```
<style>
    #ColBox { width:40px; height:40px; }
</style>
<script>
    function func(el){
        var col=$(el).val();
        if ( col=="blue" || col=="red" || col=="green" ){
            $(el).css({"color":col});
            $("#ColBox").css({"background":col});
        } else {
            $(el).val("try again").css({"color":"black"});
        }
    }
</script>
<div>
<div>hello</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
        <input id="one" type="text" onBlur="func(this);">
        <input id="two" type="text" onBlur="func(this);">
        <input id="three" type="text" onBlur="func(this);">
    </div>
    <div id="ColBox">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```